# Why do I get a syntax error for omitting a semicolon after one #10, but it is not needed for others?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, test-bench

My friend wrote an FSM code that generates 3 numbers (1,4,1) in binary.

The code works and compiles in modelsim.

I wrote a testbench for it so I can simulate it.

The testbench code errors in line 24 and says this:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/******/*****/fsm/fsm_tb.v(24): near "end": syntax error, unexpected end.
```

Which indicates that `end` is unexpected after the previous line `#10`. So maybe there is a semicolon missing, but I don't have semicolons in the other lines `#10` either, so I do not understand the problem.

This is the actual FSM code

```
module fsm_detector (
  input wire clk,
  input wire in,
  output wire out
);

parameter s0 = 0, s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, s4 = 4, s5 = 5, s6 = 6, s7 = 7, s8 = 8, s9 = 9, s10 = 10;

reg [3:0] state, next_state;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  state <= next_state;
end

always @* begin
  case (state)
    s0:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s1;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s1:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s2;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s2:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s3;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s3:  begin
      if (in == 1'b1) next_state = s4;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s4:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s5;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s5:  begin
      if (in == 1'b1) next_state = s6;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s6:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s7;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s7:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s8;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s8:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s9;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s9:  begin
      if (in == 1'b0) next_state = s10;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
    s10: begin
      if (in == 1'b1) next_state = s0;
      else next_state = s0;
    end
  endcase
end

assign out = (state == s10);

endmodule
```

This is the test bench I wrote:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module fsm_detector_tb;

reg clk;
reg in;
wire out;

fsm_detector dut (
  .clk(clk),
  .in(in),
  .out(out)
);
// Initialize input and output signals
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  in = 0;
  #10
  clk = 1;
  #10
  clk = 0;
  #10
end


// Stimulus for detecting "000101000001" sequence
initial begin
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b1;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b1;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b0;
  #20 in = 1'b1;

end

endmodule
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this testbench `initial` block:

```
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  in = 0;
  #10
  clk = 1;
  #10
  clk = 0;
  #10
end
```

The fix is to add a semicolon after the last `#10`:

```
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  in = 0;
  #10
  clk = 1;
  #10
  clk = 0;
  #10;
end
```

All statements must end with a semicolon.  What is tricky about your code is that the 1st 2 times you use `#10`, you don't need the semicolon.

The compiler parsers the code like:

```
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  in = 0;
  #10 clk = 1;
  #10 clk = 0;
  #10
end
```

The `#10 clk = 1;` is the complete statement.

Also, you could use a semicolon after all 3 `#10`:

```
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  in = 0;
  #10;
  clk = 1;
  #10;
  clk = 0;
  #10;
end
```